# format specifier for bigint of mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, types, mysql-connector-python

I have my primary key declared as :

```
id bigint PRIMARY KEY
```

I want extract a certain id, and want to use it further.

```
localid = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print type(localid)
query1 = ("Select * from table_name WHERE id= %d;")
cursor.execute(query1, localid)
query2 = ("Select * from table_name WHERE id= 1;")
cursor.execute(query2)
```

1. `type(localid)` is printed as `int` currently, where the fetched value is just 2 or 3 or 45.
2. query1 does not work while query2 does.
3. Is `%d` the correct specifier? I don't think so.
4. If the number fetched is indeed out of range of the normal `int`, would `%d` be right? If not, what to use?

Extra Info: [Mysql-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) connector package used. Python 2.7

Comment: have you tried running this? does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If I use `WHERE id=1;` directly, it does work. But if I use the %d, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MySQLdb`, you only need `%s` in the `execute` function maybe.

Your [Mysql-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) is `MySQLdb` indeed.

**solution1**`:

```
query1 = ("Select * from table_name WHERE id= %s;")
cursor.execute(query1, (localid,))

Note: If args is a sequence, then %s must be used as the
      parameter placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used,
      %(key)s must be used as the placeholder.
```

**solution2**:

```
query1 = ("Select * from table_name WHERE id= %d;" % localid)
cursor.execute(query1)
```

---

**Detail explaination** in `Mysqldb.cursors`

```
class BaseCursor(__builtin__.object)
 |  A base for Cursor classes. Useful attributes:
 |  
 |  description
 |      A tuple of DB API 7-tuples describing the columns in
 |      the last executed query; see PEP-249 for details.
 |  
 |  description_flags
 |      Tuple of column flags for last query, one entry per column
 |      in the result set. Values correspond to those in
 |      MySQLdb.constants.FLAG. See MySQL documentation (C API)
 |      for more information. Non-standard extension.
 |  
 |  arraysize
 |      default number of rows fetchmany() will fetch
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  execute(self, query, args=None)
 |      Execute a query.
 |      
 |      query -- string, query to execute on server
 |      args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query.
 |      
 |      Note: If args is a sequence, then %s must be used as the   #notice
 |      parameter placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used,
 |      %(key)s must be used as the placeholder.
 |      
 |      Returns long integer rows affected, if any
 |
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. The solution 2 worked. Could you tell me why my passing `localid` in cursor.execute() didn't work?

Comment: Are you using `MySQLdb`?

Comment: No, I'm using the MySQL-Python connector package.